# Silverlight XAML StringFormat : Print a number with a space as thousand separator

Tags: silverlight, xaml, numbers, string-formatting

I want to format a number like this :

**100000000** => **100 000 000** or **-1500** => **-1 500** or **-500** => **-500**

For now I'm using this method, but it doesn't work well with negative values :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat='### ### ##0'}" />
```

For example with : **-500** I got **-  500** (two spaces between '-' and '500')

Any hints ? Is it possible to do this without a converter ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid a converter in this case. You current use of spaces are treated as literals and are just injected into the final number at those character positions.

The correct format string is actually "#,##0".  The "," is actuall a directive it group digits in three digit groups and place a separator string between them.  The actual separator string uses is taken from the `NumberGroupSeparator` string property of the `NumberFormat` of the `CultureInfo` class being used by xaml.  Normally this is from the "en-US" culture and will be a comma.

There is no way to specify a custom instance of `CultureInfo` to be used so you can't manipulate the  `NumberGroupSeparator`.  Hence you will need to use an instance of a `IValueConverter`.

This console app code generates appropriate output

```
            NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo(String.Empty).NumberFormat;
            nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
            Console.WriteLine((100000000).ToString("#,##0",nfi));
            Console.WriteLine((-500).ToString("#,##0",nfi));
```